# Is there a way to offset a CSS grid item by n tracks?

Tags: css-grid, offset

Can I somehow offset an implicit track number? aka using a relative number instead of an absolute in `grid-column/row`? Example:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 66ch 1fr;
}

.item {
    grid-column: 2;
}

.special {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: /* current position -1 */
}
```